# How to avoid jautodoc generating comments for lombok annotation

Tags: eclipse, jautodoc

I am using lombok+ jautodoc in eclipse. Problem is if I use jautodoc it generates doc for 
@Buidler and @AllArgsConstructor annotation of lombok. How can I avoid that?